# Issue with pivot table query . I am using this in django as a raw query on a postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT Name,'1','2','3'
FROM (
    SELECT
        database_jobdefect.defect_id,
        database_session.name,
        count(*) AS cu
    FROM
        database_session IN ner
        JOIN database_job ON database_job.session_id = database_session.id
        INNER JOIN database_jobdefect ON database_job.id = database_jobdefect.job_id
    GROUP BY
        database_session.name,
        database_jobdefect.defect_id) PIVOT (count(database_session.name)
        FOR database_jobdefect.defect_id IN ([1],[2],[3]))
```

The error i am getting is

> "ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1:
>   ...on.name,database_jobdefect.defect_id) PIVOT (count(database_..."

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I loathe the syntax, but Postgres does have a crosstab function using the `tablefunc` extensions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Comment: Why do you expect SQL Server syntax to work with Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't support `pivot` syntax.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE djd.defect_id = 1) THEN defect_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE djd.defect_id = 2) THEN defect_2,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE djd.defect_id = 3) THEN defect_3
FROM database_session ds JOIN
     database_job dj 
     ON dj.session_id = ds.id JOIN
        database_jobdefect djd
     ON dj.id = djd.job_id 
GROUP BY ds.name;
```